# What does it mean to "admit" something in vector calculus?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, potential-theory

Trying to understand the Helmholtz decomposition has lead me to the concept of a vector potential.  From Wikipedia [1]:

> If a vector field v admits a vector potential A, then [...]

I've searched for a definition of this word here, on Wikipedia, on Wolfram, and just by googling.  It seems a very common word in this field, but I've not been able to nail down its definition in this context.

Thanks in advance!  (I wasn't quite sure how to tag this--I hope the tags aren't too broad.)

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_potential

Comment: It means, "if *there exists* a vector potential $A$..."

Comment: By "exist" do you mean "is defined" or "is nonzero"?

Comment: It means $v$ has a vector potential $A$, i.e., there exists $A$, such that $\nabla \times A=v$.

Comment: Thanks--that makes sense.  If you want to write that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @KittyL just pinging you in case you want to write an answer as PyNewb suggests

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt Sure. Thank you. :) I just realized that if you don't write with other's name, they wouldn't get the message of the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means $\vec{v}$ has a vector potential $\vec{A}$, i.e., there exists a vector field $\vec{A}$, such that $$\nabla \times \vec{A}=\vec{v}$$